# Can my UA revised ranger's animal companion use Coordinated Attack if I am riding it?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, unearthed-arcana, mounted-combat

If I'm riding my animal companion for my class ([UA revised ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf)), can my animal companion make an attack using the following ability?

> #### Coordinated Attack
>
> Beginning at 5th level, you and your animal companion form a more potent fighting team. When you use the Attack action on your turn, if your companion can see you, it can use its reaction to make a melee attack.

Comment: To be clear about what you're asking - is your concern here around the clause 'if your companion can see you'? Is it around applying the PHB rules for Mounted Combat to a Beastmaster companion? Or, is it something else? Why do you think your animal companion might not be able to attack in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes.

When mounted you have two options. Control the mount (if it will let you) or allow it to act independently.

If controlled, the following applies:

> The initiative of a controlled mount changes to match yours when you mount it. It moves
> as you direct it, and it has only three action options: Dash,
> Disengage, and Dodge.

This restriction applies to actions not reactions. Therefore it may take the reaction described in "Coordinated Attack " and attack:

> **Coordinated Attack**
>
> Beginning at 5th level, when you use the Attack action on your turn, if your companion can see you, **it can use its reaction** to make a melee attack against any creature within range.

If acting independently then:

> A controlled mount can move and act even on the
> turn that you mount it.  An independent mount retains its place in the
> initiative order. Bearing a rider puts no restrictions on the actions
> the mount can take, and it moves and acts as it wishes.

Since there are no restrictions, it may make the reactionary attack in this scenario also.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.